# Running Map() in parallel on multiple cores?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Given a dataframe with a 2 columns of JSON lists like this:

```
col1
"[34454,31843,33239,34885,34352,42294,26603,55449,34710,49235,37558,82942,38028,58170,42772,27700,28464,28917,31902,41082,37089,67366,48616,46706,31464,30308,33832,30485,50838,38225,59758,47311,33747,32972,34903,32729,52274,38895,45899,32511,31189,33756,32684,47994,38019,31623,31751,32144,32398,44909,36542,160950,59383,53569,39797,36029,15031,15031,113913,33540,106166,62518,36407,44354,36237,47610]"
```

....

```
col2
"[14,7,5,3,4,0,1,7,2,3,1,18,13,4,23,7,8,8,11,18,15,6,2,10,2,4,8,5,11,5,1,5,2,4,3,1,6,8,5,5,3,1,1,4,5,2,9,3,4,11,11,14,3,12,2,6,0,0,15,1,18,5,3,6,6,6]"
```

I have given an example of one row but actually I have millions of rows with col1 and col2.

I want to apply the following formula: `col1/number1 / col2/ number2`
where `number1` and `number2` are just numbers like `1,3,4 ...`

Here is what I have done so far and I need your help to do it faster using parallel computing with multiple cores like `parallel::parSapply`.

```
Map(`/`, lapply(df$col1, function(i) {fromJSON(i) / number1}), 
              lapply(df$col2, function(i) {fromJSON(i) / number2}))
```

Please advise how to run Map or any analog but in parallel using my cores.

Comment: Why not use `parallel::mcMap()` ?

Comment: @docendodiscimus would you be so kind and comment if I am write:
`n_cores = detectCores() - 1
cl = makeCluster(n_cores)
clusterExport(cl, "df", envir = environment())
mcMap(cl = cl, '/', lapply(df$col1, function(i) {fromJSON(i) / number1}), 
              lapply(df$col2, function(i) {fromJSON(i) / number2})`

Comment: @jaap can you help please?

Comment: @akrun maybe you can help me out here?

Comment: Not sure what `fromJSON` do but here it doesn't seem that you make lots of computation, it's merely accessing the data. In this case, not sure parallelism will help you.